# Error while changing identity for application pool

Tags: c#, windows, iis, azure

I try change identity for application pool on Windows Azure. My project uses this application pool when works on Windows Azure. By default application pool uses NetworkService identity, but I must use another identity. I try change it in `OnStart()` event of WebRole by this way:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{                       
    string appPoolName =
    serverManager.Sites[RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id + "_Web"]
    .Applications.First().ApplicationPoolName;

    var appPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools[appPoolName];

    appPool.ProcessModel.UserName = Environment.MachineName + "\\UserName";

    appPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;

    appPool.ProcessModel.Password = "UserPassword";

    serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

But I get exception with next message:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80090016): 
       Keyset does not exist (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090016)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.AppHostWritableAdminManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationManager.CommitChanges()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager.CommitChanges()
   at Project.Web.WebRole.OnStart() in E:\Projects\...\Web\WebRole.cs:line 57
```

If I change identity in IIS manager I don't get any error. What is wrong with my code and why do I get this error?

Comment: branch and bound and separation of concerns. Can you first of all try to debug and only apply a small change and see if CommitChanges works or still fails? comment out your code for the identity and see if you manage to change another property...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, here is my answer. This error occurs because NetworkService identity doesn't have Read access on the iisWasKey key. More information and how to resolve this problem I found here: ["Keyset does not exist" error message when you try to change the identity of an application pool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977754)

Answer (score 2):

Updates to the applicationHost.config require administrative privileges.  When you run locally, you are an administrator.  In the cloud, your RoleEntryPoint runs as a normal user unless you elevate the role.  Have you done so?

Check to see if you have `<Runtime executionContext="elevated"/>` specified inside your role declaration in ServiceDefinition.csdef.

**Edit**:  Wade also showed how to do this using a slightly different method (check the comments).  [Try this as well](http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/)

Comment: Thank you! I tried do this http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/ but I got another exception